# how can I send an IP messaging using twilio-csharp library

Tags: javascript, c#, api, twilio, messaging

I just start create a live chat app with Twilio. 
I have downloaded the twilio-csharp library from twilio.com/docs/csharp/install and started with a sample console application.

code example from Twilio:

```js
// Download the twilio-csharp library from twilio.com/docs/csharp/install
using System;
using Twilio.IpMessaging;

class Example {
    static void Main (string[] args) {
        // Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/user/account
        const string accountSid = "accountSid";
        const string authToken = "authToken";
        const string serviceSid = "serviceSid";
        const string channelSid = "channelSid";

        // List all Messages
        var client = new IpMessagingClient(accountSid, authToken);
        MessageResult result = client.ListMessages(serviceSid, channelSid);

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

But this code doesn't work in my case, I got always an errors "type or namespace could not be found". 
[image]

I have these like reference:

[image]

I tried tutorial of IP Messaging , it works. But in the tutorial, they used Javascript SDK to initialize the IP messaging client

```js
tc.accessManager = new Twilio.AccessManager(tokenResponse.token);
tc.messagingClient = new Twilio.IPMessaging.Client(tc.accessManager);
```

So I just don't understand how can I use this C# library to send an IP Messaging, or maybe I can just control my IP Messaging applications from the client side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I unstand why I got this error.
I just follow the steps of installation on twilio-csharp library gitHub. But this project's README is only for SMS project. If we want to use Library for IpMessaging, we must also import another Library, [Twilio.IpMessaging](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging).

[image]

So What I got know like reference and the project IP Messaging works.
[image]
[image]

Hope this will help the others.